# Show only first two items in ddlb - Power Builder 12.5

Tags: powerbuilder

Is there any way to show only first few items in the ddlb?

I have one ddlb where there are 7 items in it.

However, I want to show only first 2 instead of all.

This is non-pfc

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to a dropdownlistbox control at some point the items in the list were inserted via the 'InsertItem' or 'AddItem' methods.  You could try to add logic to this to only add the items you want or you could use the 'DeleteItem' method to remove the 'extra' items you don't want to show.  This control does not have any 'filtering'.  If you are using a dropdowndatawindow of some sort you could use a filter on the child datawindow.

Comment: yes, I am using dropdownlistbox control.

Comment: I use deleteitem in the end. Check whether the text is the want I want, if yes, keep it, else delete it. Thank you.